# Зависимость между выпадающими списками

Tags: java, android

Имеется: 3 поля для ввода пользователем, одно из которых для вывода результата. Если пользователь вводил значения в поля, то в третьем автоматически считалась сумма.

Теперь я добавляю выпадающие списки к 1му и 2му полю, и новое - итоговое поле для третьего выпадающего списка. 3й выпадающий список с новым полем должен считать сумму выбранной в нем категории.

Как реализовать ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: приведите пример. Ничего не понятно.

Comment: Если у 3го выпадающего списка выбраны Продукты, то должно выводить сумму по товарам, у которых выбраны Продукты

Comment: ну, пройдитесь по остальным Spinner'ам, и проверьте, если у них тоже выбраны продукты, значит добавить к сумме.